# Using a PNP to enable a NPN current source not yielding expected current

Tags: npn, pnp, reed-switch

Hi I am trying to switch on a brake light with a reed switch. The load is a 12v (0.1A) LED bike light. The following circuit works in the sense that the light comes on when the magnet moves away from the reed switch but the total amount of current i measure is only around 40mA (quite dim) but i am expecting around double this with the resistors i have used.

I have tested the LED just with the PNP and it pulls around 134ma.

[image: circuit with reed switch]

Comment: Are you sure of your component values? Are Q7 and the 7ohm resistor close to each other?

Comment: I hope you’re not testing this in a solderless breadboard.

Comment: yes its on a solderless breadboard. Q7 and 7ohm are close.